# Using only a small part of Bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The vast majority of pages on our site will only use GRID and NAVBAR. It makes no sense for us to be loading all of jQuery and bootstrap.min.js on each page.

In fact, the only JS needed at all is the js to handle the opening/closing of NAVBAR on mobile requests.

1. Is there a way to minimize bootstrap 4 like there is in 3 (i.e. selecting only the components you need)?
2. Is there a way to use NAVBAR without jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason not to load the entirety of bootstrap/jquery?  If you ever integrate something that requires it all, you'll have several bugs.  It shouldn't take long to load it all.

Answer (score 0):

@Terry

Bootstrap 4 isn't production ready yet, so I don't think there might be official tools such as Customizer available right now. However, I found this project on Github: http://bdavidxyz.github.io/yourown-bootstrap4/

Take a look at it!

Hope it helps!